# Calling HTTPS from HTTP through AJAX for login

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, https, jsonp

I know its violates the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and that is why it is not possible through simple ajax request. I could use JSONP. But using JSONP for login doesn't sound secure ( no post only get ).

So is there a more secure way of implementing login into https through ajax ?

Comment: Yes, take `HTTP` out of the equation. If you perform a `GET` request with origin within `HTTP` it's cleartext. Otherwise, put a re-direct on the server to force `HTTP` to `HTTPS` on the login page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not only does it violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but since the page you are calling from is insecure it has the potential to be interfered with and leak all the data you are trying to keep secure.

Use HTTPS for the entire process.

Better yet, keep using HTTPS while people are logged in, otherwise you will have [the Firesheep problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep).

Comment: I understand that I would risk that. But since none of the content on the website is user generated, it kind of reduces the risk of being interfered. The login service is in HTTPS, and I want to call it from http

Comment: Also I can't use https for all the pages logged in, its a media heavy website, and https affect on cache can really slow down my website.

Comment: @Quentin can you elaborate on what the risks are?  How would the data get leaked?

Comment: Man-in-the-middle attack modifies the calling page. User enters their credentials. Calling page sends credentials to the attacker as well as the secure server.

Comment: @Quentin Good Point.  So I guess it's a good deal less secure to hardcore attackers.  but if you're just sniffing packets it is 'secure'.

Comment: @Quentin I understand that but every popular site facebook,twitter etc. etc. are doing that. I am aware of that attack

Comment: Why has no one mentioned CORS?

Comment: @AlxVallejo — Because using CORS to give access to an HTTPS page from an HTTP makes a big dent in the security of HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

As we've discussed in the comments below, this is what Facebook does for their registration page, although there are some vulnerabilities to this method.  While it won't appear secure to the user (no lock icon), the actual request is done over HTTPS.   If you controlled the entirety of the receiving page, there would be nothing less secure about doing a JSONP request over GET.  However, a man-in-the-middle attack could modify the receiving page on load, and cause the returned credentials to be sent to an attacker.

On the plus side though, no one that's just sniffing packets is going to be able to get the credentials: an attack would have to be fairly targeted.

Regarding cookies, technically, JSONP could "return" cookies; you'd just return name-value pairs of the cookies you wanted to set, and have a function on the receiving page set them.

But unless the browser treats `<script>`s differently, and it might, you should be able to set a cookie in the normal way using the Response Headers of your JSONP response.

Comment: I want to make it easier for people to register on my website. Which again needs to be secure. So when someone clicks on register. I put a popup for registering and when he clicks register i wanted that to happen through ajax.

Comment: @MarutiB It's times like these that I default to 'I wonder what facebook does', and it turns out they do pretty much exactly what you are trying to do.  So maybe you're okay.  But yeah, JSONP or straight up including rendered javascript from the https site (same idea as JSONP) is your only solution.  More about cookies above.

Comment: I know :( I guess a little cost to pay in security for improving User Experience.

Comment: My only question would be. Can JSONP be hacked ? I am unable to find a usecase. Maybe I will start another question.

Comment: @MarutiB I might be being retarded but why does it matter if it's a POST or a GET?  The url is constructed *on* the page, and the browser uses HTTPS to retrieve it, so it should be okay.  If someone intercepts the request, they could get the POST parameters as easily as the GET ones.

Comment: The more I think about this the more it seems okay.

Comment: @MarutiB — The only security that POST will give you is stopping people reading the URL of the whole by looking over the user's shoulder (assuming that the server is configured not to log the query strings in the access.log).

Comment: @MarutiB — No, they can't. The data is encrypted over HTTPS. It is only available at the end points.